# JFrame executes infinite times while using componentResized() of ComponentListener() in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have added a `ComponentListener` in JFrame and in its `componentResized()` method I kept some codes inside it which makes the application execute infinite window. This is because I have created an object of the class inside the `componentResized()` method. Here what I am trying to do is access the method of its inner class `BottomPanel()`.I have attached my executable code here.

```
  package nonResponsiveButtons;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
    import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.application.Platform;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class NonResponsiveButtons extends JFrame {
    private int applicationWidth_600 = 600;
    private int applicationHeight_600 = 600;

    private int upperPanelHeight_500 = 500;
    private int bottomPanelHeight_100 = (applicationWidth_600-upperPanelHeight_500); 

    /**
     * 
     * @return the height of the jframe
     */
    public int getJframeHeight(){
        return this.getHeight();        
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the width of the jframe
     */
    public int getJframeWidth(){
        return this.getWidth();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NonResponsiveButtons();
    }



    public NonResponsiveButtons(){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                new JFXPanel();
                BottomPanel bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();
                add(bottomPanel);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error in swing utilities thread :" + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

        this.setSize(applicationWidth_600, applicationHeight_600);
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            //gets executed every time
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Component resized");
                NonResponsiveButtons nrb = new NonResponsiveButtons();  //this code creates a new window

                NonResponsiveButtons.BottomPanel nonResponsiveBottmPanel = nrb.new BottomPanel();  //this code always creates a new window

                nonResponsiveBottmPanel.centeriseBottomPanelComponents();               

            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        add(jPanel());              
        setVisible(true);
    }



    private JPanel jPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(applicationWidth_600,upperPanelHeight_500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        return panel;
    }

    private class BottomPanel extends JPanel{
        private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
        private HBox scenePane;
        private Button btn1;
        private Button btn2;
        private Button btn3;

        private BottomPanel(){
            setSize(applicationWidth_600, bottomPanelHeight_100);
            setLocation(0, upperPanelHeight_500);
            setLayout(null);



            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    /// putting all the buttons inside the scenePane                    
                    getScenePane().getChildren().addAll(getBtn1(),getBtn2(),getBtn3());                 
                    ///adding scenePane to the fxPanel 
                    getjfxPanel().setScene(new Scene(getScenePane()));                  
                }

            });

            add(getjfxPanel());
        }

        public void centeriseBottomPanelComponents() {
            getJframeHeight();
            getJframeWidth();
            System.out.println("Jframe's height is : " + getJframeHeight() + " & " + "Jframe's width is : " + getJframeWidth());
        }

    /**
     * Disposing the components of the bottom panel
     */
        private void disposeBottomPanel(){
            getScenePane().getChildren().removeAll();           
        }

        private JFXPanel getjfxPanel(){
            if(jfxPanel == null){
                jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                jfxPanel.setSize(applicationWidth_600,bottomPanelHeight_100);

            }
            return jfxPanel;
        }

        private HBox getScenePane(){
            if(scenePane == null){
                scenePane = new HBox();
                scenePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#666666");
                scenePane.setLayoutX(100);
                scenePane.setSpacing(50);
            }
            return scenePane;
        }

        /*
         * using getters will avoid :-
         * 1. null pointer exceptions
         * 2. standard coding format
         * 3. makex programming felxible
         */
        private Button getBtn1(){
            if(btn1 == null){
                btn1 = new Button("Button 1");
                btn1.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn1.setLayoutX(80);

                btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                        disposeBottomPanel();
                        } catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("Error disposing the components :" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        System.out.println("Btn1 event handler");
                    }
                });
            }
            return btn1;
        }
        private Button getBtn2(){
            if(btn2 == null){
                btn2 = new Button("Button 2");
                btn2.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn2.setLayoutX(80);
            }
            return btn2;
        }
        private Button getBtn3(){
            if(btn3 == null){
                btn3 = new Button("Button 3");
                btn3.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn3.setLayoutX(80);
            }
            return btn3;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating local variable `BottomPanel bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();` declare the class field `BottomPanel bottomPanelInstance;` and create it just once on initializing.

In your componentResized() method just access the field `bottomPanelInstance` and call

```
bottomPanelInstance.centeriseBottomPanelComponents();
```

Comment: Thank you @StanislavL it worked. What mistake was I doing? And where did it go wrong

Comment: You created frame again and again but actually you need just one instance. With your approach the reference to the panel was lost and your were wrying to acess the newly created one.

Comment: If an answer works, accept it. It helps future users facing the same problem :)